# Regressao Segmentada no R

Tags: r, regressão

Estava estudando um pouco sobre `regressão segmentada` e alguns exemplos executados no `R` e estou com duvidas sobre o funcionamento do `segmented`. Eu preciso sempre definir onde os pontos de quebra deverão existir?

O `R` não disponibiliza alguma função que estime o valor dos pontos de quebras de acordo com a distribuição dos meus dados?

Comment: Nunca usei o pacote, mas talvez você possa mesma possa fazer um script que testa diferentes pontos e compara os resultados, se não forem muitos pontos talvez dê um bom resultado.

Comment: Pois é.. eu tinha visto a utilização do piecewise.linear do pacote SiZer e, pelo que entendi, ele pede pra que você defina o ponto de quebra.. outras soluções que estendem o mesmo conceito permitem que sejam definidos mais pontos de quebra.. mas eu deveria dar como entrada os valores. Minha dúvida é existe a possibilidade da própria função definir onde seriam esses breakpoints sem necessidade de indicá-los.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considere o exemplo do `help(segmented)`
Para ajustar o modelo de regressão segmentada, primeiro você precisa ajustar o modelo de regressão linear.

```
set.seed(12)
xx<-1:100
zz<-runif(100)
yy<-2+1.5*pmax(xx-35,0)-1.5*pmax(xx-70,0)+15*pmax(zz-.5,0)+rnorm(100,0,2)
dati<-data.frame(x=xx,y=yy,z=zz)
out.lm<-lm(y~x,data=dati)
```

A função `segmented` sempre estima os breakpoints. Se você fornecer valores iniciais por meio do parâmetro `psi`, o número de breakpoints que ele estima é o mesmo que o tamanho do vetor que você passou.

```
> m.s <- segmented(m, seg.Z = ~x, psi = c(25, 80))
> m.s
Call: segmented.lm(obj = m, seg.Z = ~x, psi = c(25, 80))

Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
(Intercept)            x            z         U1.x         U2.x  
    1.12868     -0.06976      8.72782      1.55907     -1.54130  

Estimated Break-Point(s):
psi1.x  psi2.x  
 34.37   70.56
```

Veja acima os valores estimados p/ os breakpoints.

Você também pode não fornecer nenhum valor inicial (`psi = NA`), e neste caso fornecer apenas o número de breakpoints que você quer utilizar por meio do parâmetro `K` na função `seg.control`.

```
> m.s <- segmented(m, seg.Z = ~x, psi = NA, control = seg.control(K = 2))
> m.s
Call: segmented.lm(obj = m, seg.Z = ~x, psi = NA, control = seg.control(K = 2))

Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
(Intercept)            x            z         U1.x         U2.x  
    1.11308     -0.06832      8.72422      1.55716     -1.54335  

Estimated Break-Point(s):
psi1.x  psi2.x  
 34.39   70.61
```

**Note** que o valor padrão de `K` é 10 e por isso, se seu banco de dados não tiver tantos pontos de mudança, você terá problemas de estimação se não fornecer `K`.

Comment: Isso mesmo, Daniel. Deu certo com segmented. Obrigada